# How to deep compare maps to filter distinct items in XQuery?

Tags: filter, maps, xquery, deepequals

I wish I could filter a list of maps to remove those that are identical.

The `union` operator of XQuery only works on nodes. The

How can I do a deep comparison of maps to output distinct maps ? I can suppose that the function `deep-equal()` could be useful there with higher order function but I couldn’t cope with it.

```
let $map1 := map{ 
  'a' : '1',
  'b' : '2'
}
let $map2 := map{ 
  'c' : '3',
  'd' : '4'
}
let $map3 := map{ 
  'a' : '1',
  'b' : '2'
}
return local:getDistinctMap( ($map1, $map2, $map3) )
```

That should return

```
map{ 
  'a' : '1',
  'b' : '2'
}
map{ 
  'c' : '3',
  'd' : '4'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fold-left`:

```
declare function local:getDistinctMaps($maps as map(*)*) as map(*)* {
  fold-left(
    $maps, 
    (),
    function($distinct-maps, $new-map) { 
      if (some $map in $distinct-maps satisfies deep-equal($map, $new-map))
      then $distinct-maps else ($distinct-maps, $new-map)
    }
  )
};

let $map1 := map{ 
  'a' : '1',
  'b' : '2'
}
let $map2 := map{ 
  'c' : '3',
  'd' : '4'
}
let $map3 := map{ 
  'a' : '1',
  'b' : '2'
}
return local:getDistinctMaps( ($map1, $map2, $map3) )
```

Comment: That's going to be expensive, of course. If there are lots of these maps and you need a more efficient solution, then you need to write a function that computes some kind of hash code for each map, so you only need to do a deep comparison of maps whose hash codes are equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the precision. I can imagine it’s the reason why union operators are not available for maps